# Python : Multiple loops at the same time that execute regular intervals (convert AutoHot key script in python)

Tags: python, loops, python-asyncio, autohotkey, intervals

I am using Python to make keyboard key toggle on/off multiple loops at the same time that execute every [1-5s] each independently.
basically I would like to replicate AutoHotkey script in Python.

Once a loop has started I need the pynput code to keep listening to key presses and be able to start/stop any loop.
One of the issues I have is how to use asyncio to replicate the settimer function from AHK (The SetTimer function causes a function to be called automatically and repeatedly at a specified time interval. You can do other actions while it is running).

My current Python code

```
import pyautogui,time
import random
from random import randint
import time
from time import sleep
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import threading
from datetime import datetime 
import asyncio

toggle1 = False


def start_loop1():
    start_time = time.time()

    async def stuff():
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)
        print(round(time.time() - start_time, 1), "Finished doing stuff")

    async def do_stuff_periodically(interval, periodic_function):
        while True:
            print(round(time.time() - start_time, 1), "Starting periodic function")
            await asyncio.gather(
                asyncio.sleep(interval),
                periodic_function(),
            )
            global toggle1
            print("toggle1 STATE:", toggle1)
            toggle1 = not toggle1
            if toggle1== False:
                task.cancel()
    task= asyncio.run(do_stuff_periodically(5, stuff))





def on_press(key):
#    print('{0} pressed'.format(key)) 
    if key.char in ("a"):
        global toggle1
        toggle1 = not toggle1
        print("toggle1 STATE:", toggle1)
        if toggle1:
            start_loop1()
            
        return False
        

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
        
# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The aHK code I m trying to replicate

```
Random(Min := "", Max := "")
{
    Random Out, % Min, % Max
    return out
}
Toggle := 0
*a::
    Toggle := !Toggle
            if Toggle 
            {
            send {a down}
            settimer, Loop1, 10130, on
                settimer, Loop2, 6185, on
            sleep,% Random(30,60 )
            send {q}
            sleep,% Random(30,60 )
            send {r}
                } else {
            settimer, Loop1, off
                settimer, Loop2, off
            send {a up}
                }

return

Loop1: 
    send {q}
    SetTimer, Loop1,off
    SetTimer, Loop1, % Random(10200,10230 ),on  
return

Loop2: 
    send {r}
    SetTimer, Loop2,off
    SetTimer, Loop2, % Random(6220,6245 ),on
return
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, using the [`keyboard` module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

```py
import time
import threading
import logging
from queue import Queue
import keyboard

def do_something():
    ... # do whatever
    

class StopMessage:
    ...

LOOP1_QUEUE = Queue() # queue to contain stop messages

def loop1():
    while True:
        if not LOOP1_QUEUE.empty():
            t = LOOP1_QUEUE.get()
            assert t is StopMessage, 'unexpected queue contents'
            LOOP1_QUEUE.task_done()
            break # stop the loop
        do_something() # otherwise keep doing things
        time.sleep(0.1)
LOOP2_QUEUE = Queue()
def loop2():
   ...
   # basically the same as loop1, but with a different queue
   # maybe different ``do_something``, wait times, or whatever
   # this can be generalized, if you want.


queues = [LOOP1_QUEUE, LOOP2_QUEUE]
threads = []

startstop_lock = threading.Lock()


def start_loops():
    assert not threads, 'must stop loops before they can be started'
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=loop1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop2)
    t1.start(); t2.start()
    threads = [t1, t2]

def stop_loops():
    assert threads, 'threads must be started in order to be stopped'
    for q in queues:
        q.put(StopMessage)
    for q in queues:
        q.join()
    while threads:
        t = threads.pop()
        t.join()

def is_running():
    return bool(threads)

def startstop():
    with startstop_lock:
        if not is_running():
            start_loops()
        else:
            stop_loops()

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a', startstop)

def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  
        # can do other things in the main thread
        # while everything else happens in the background.
        # or just do nothing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a rough approximation of the AHK code you provided.